# Postgres function json_array_elements does not found while django's tests

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I have class method in django model which is using `json_array_elements` function.

In case when it performs by browser it works fine.
But in tests it fails.
`python manage.py test`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_project/dj_server/model_animations/tests.py", line 94, in test_cteating
    response_first = model_animations.views.get_animations_list(request, groupid)
  File "path_to_project/dj_server/model_animations/views.py", line 37, in get_animations_list
    for model_anim in listArray:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1535, in __iter__
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 76, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 90, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: function json_array_elements(text) does not exist
LINE 1: ...on_name FROM model_animations_model, json_array...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**in models.py**

```
@classmethod
def animations_list(self, group_id):
    if group_id:
        try:
            listArray = ModelAnimationList.objects.raw(('SELECT * FROM model_animations_model, json_array_elements(animated_groups) AS data WHERE \'"%s"\' = data::text' %group_id))
            return listArray
        except:
            pass
    return None
```

**in views.py**
def get_animations_list(request, group_id):
    ...

```
listArray = ModelAnimationList.animations_list(group_id)
if listArray:
    for model_anim in listArray:
        if model_anim:
            anim_dict = { 'a_id'  : model_anim.id, 'a_name' : model_anim.animation_name }
            result_anim_list.append(anim_dict)

...
```

**in tests.py**

```
request = HttpRequest()
response_first = model_animations.views.get_animations_list(request, groupid)
```

Installed: 
python 2.7 
Django 1.7.1 
Postgres 9.3.5 
psycopg2 2.5.4 
Mac 10.10 yosemite

Comment: Could you please post the code for your failing test cases?

Comment: oh, it's a lot of code. I will try make something simple.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Mistake in query `json_array_elements(animated_groups)`

Needs change to this:
`json_array_elements(animated_groups::json)`

Comment: For me, I had to use `to_jsonb`. E.g. `json_array_elements(to_jsonb(items))`

Answer (score 9):

Postgres JSON processing functions such as `json_array_elements(animated_groups::json)`, `jsonb_array_elements(animated_groups::jsonb)` will take `json` or `jsonb` values.

Because postgres JSON field(`animated_groups`) are store as text format or binary format.
so we need to convert the type by using either `::json` or `::jsonb` it give the json or jsonb format

check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)